# Use two or three SQL tables in dropdown list PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a **dropdown list** which is **connected to my database**  (it's for an intern project)  and **one table** (table name : voucher) and in this table we have an **attribute** named (**code**)

I display all the "code" which are in the table in the dropdown list.

I also have 2 other tables (description and operateur). Can I use a jointure to join for example the column "code" in the 'voucher' table to the column "desc_text" in the 'description' table?

The point is that i want to display the “desc_text“( basically a description text)  who is Linked to the code 'voucher' table when i click on the “code“ in the dropdown list and i submit with a submit button and i want the “ desc_text “ to be displayed in the other page.

What should i do?

I thought of something like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<option value="' . $row['code'] . '"';
if($row['code'] == $desc_text) { echo ' selected';} ;
echo '>' . $row['desc_text'] . ' ' . $row['desc_text'] . '</option>';
}
```

**The code i used for the dropdown list:**

```
    <div class="select" style="width:200px;">
    <?php
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi ('localhost','root','root','pdodb');

$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT code, description FROM voucher");
?>
<select class=" form-control-lg" name="list" id="codelist" >
<?php
while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
    $code = $rows['code'];
    $description = $rows['description'];
    echo "<option  value='$code'>$code</option>";
}
?>
</div>
</select>
```

**operateur**

[image: operateur table]

**description**
[image: description table]

**voucher**
[image: voucher table]

Comment: i join the pictures of the tables

Comment: A column called `code` and one called `desc_text` dont sound like they would contain the same kind of data??

Comment: Thanks Riggs for your answer, they both share '' text '' data

Comment: But do they share **THE SAME** text data, if not then of course `if($row['code'] == $desc_text)` that IF will do nothing useful

Comment: no they dont share the same text data, the code will be something like '' RIGGS '' and the desc_text will be '' This person name is Riggs , he is working on ...'' (example) and i need to connect the both data, if i click on a specific code it will echo the description who is bind to it

Comment: i think i need to work with ID?